# What exactly is the nobalance option in Matlab eig function?

Tags: matlab, eigenvector, eigenvalue

In Matlab you can issue the [`eig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) function with the `'nobalance'` option. What exactly does it do differently from the default one?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#bti99ts-1 Matlab uses numerical methods to do matrix decomposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#bti99ts-1) documentation:

> Balance option, specified as one two strings: `'balance'`, which enables a preliminary balancing step, or `'nobalance'` which disables it. In most cases, the balancing step improves the conditioning of `A` to produce more accurate results. However, there are cases in which balancing produces incorrect results. **Specify `'nobalance'` when `A` contains values whose scale differs dramatically.** For example, if `A` contains nonzero integers, as well as very small (near zero) values, then the balancing step might scale the small values to make them as significant as the integers and produce inaccurate results.

---

EDIT: A related function [`balance`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/balance.html) is said to be the default preceding step in `eig`.

Note a few lines in the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/balance.html) - "The ill conditioning is concentrated in the scaling matrix" .... "If a matrix contains small elements that are due to roundoff error, balancing might scale them up to make them as significant as the other elements of the original matrix."

So, my answer to @Isopycnal's question is "`nobalance` suppresses amplification of round-off errors, when dealing with ill-conditioned matrices". Here are a few points that may help -

- "balancing" a matrix `A` is essentially performing a similarity transformation `B = T\A*T` where `B` is called as a "balanced matrix".
- by balancing a *good-conditioned* matrix (which means it has reasonable scale), the "asymmetry" is concentrated into the scaling matrix, `T`. According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) of `eig`, "In most cases, the balancing step improves the conditioning of A to produce more accurate results. "
- however, balancing an *ill-conditioned* (means very large scale) matrix will scale up the round-off errors, because Matlab is trying to make the small values (such as `1e-9`) as significant as the large ones (say `1e10`). *Without careful thinking* it's already known that the result will be less precise.

I know it has something to do with the matrix decomposition algorithms which Matlab picks when performing `eig`, eg "Pencil decomposition LU factorization etc", as @EJG89 has pointed out. But it's too deeply buried in my memory to recall :( Anyone who knows how Matlab perform commands like `eig` please consider expanding this answer! Thanks!

Comment: Do you happen to know which algorithm is used?

Comment: @EJG89 Matlab implements several techniques to do eigenvector/eigenvalue calculations. When I was learning numerical method I was taught it uses iteration-based decomposition techniques, of which the names I couldn't remember. The point is those methods could fail when input matrix is "ill" (has very large scale) (if I could remember that's because the iteration can't reach a small error)

Comment: Ah it all comes back to me now. Pencil decomposition LU factorization etc. I think MatLab uses standard diagonal balancing.

Comment: Found a related function `balance`. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/balance.html It is said to be the default preceding step in `eig`. Note a few lines - "_The ill conditioning is concentrated in the scaling matrix_" "_If a matrix contains small elements that are due to roundoff error, balancing might scale them up to make them as significant as the other elements of the original matrix._"

Comment: @Yvon just turned my answer to a "community wiki" - do feel free to update its body to reflect your findings!

Comment: Thank you, @Shai! This discussion extends my knowledge of numerical methods so I'm glad to add to the answer, and happier to see more ideas/comments/corrections in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately `balance.m` is closed-source; see [matrix-balancing-algorithm](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24937/matrix-balancing-algorithm) on scicomp.stack .

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, the balancing method is along the lines of LAPACK's `?GEBAL` and `?GEBAK` routines but some testing suggests that there are some modifications as the results differ occasionally.

The balancing helps to improve the conditioning via similarity transformations. However, in some cases balancing actually makes the problem worse. The documented cases include Hessenberg matrices and matrices with numerical noise that is amplified by the scaling which the algorithm tries to balance with the actual data. Depending on the problem the data matrix is also permuted to bring the matrix to upper triangular form as much as possible.

The balancing algorithm can also be used via `balance.m`
Other relevant balancing routines deep in the toolboxes are `mscale.m` and `arescale.m` routines from control system toolbox which offers more refined control (excuse the pun).